# Why does $(\partial_\mu g(x))g(x)^{-1} \in T_e G$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, group-theory, vector-fields, lie-algebra

I'm reading [Folland's book](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=SURV/149) about QFT and at chapter nine he states:

> How must the Lagrangian be modified in order to remain invariant under this larger group of transformations?
>
> As before, the point is that
> $$\partial_\mu(g(x) \cdot \phi (x)) = g(x) \cdot \partial_\mu \phi(x) + \partial_\mu g(x) \cdot\phi(x)$$
> and we have to find a way to cancel
> the second term on the right. Note that $\partial_\mu g(x)$ is an
> element not of $G$ but of the tangent space to $G$ at $g(x)$ i.e: $T_{g(x)}G$; Thus
> $$(\partial_\mu g(x))g(x)^{-1}$$
> belongs to the Lie algebra $g$ of $G$
> (the tangent space to $G$ at the identity $\ldots$).

But I'm not understanding why we have that

$$(\partial_\mu g(x))g(x)^{-1} \in T_e G.$$

Thanks in advance to any hint to understanding how can does $g^{-1}$ can 'move' $\partial_\mu g(x)\in T_{g(x)}G$ to $T_e G$.

Comment: It depends on the type of representation of the group. It is possible to choose the vector space V on which the representations of the group G act as the tangent space of the group itself. It is called the adjoint representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ref. 1 assumes above that the Lie group
   $$G~\subseteq~ GL(n,\mathbb{C})~\subseteq~ {\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}),$$
   so we can view the tangent space of $G$ as imbedded in the Euclidean space ${\rm Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$.
2. In particular, if $R_g:G\to G$ denotes right multiplication with $g\in G$, that is $$ R_g(h)~:=~hg,$$ then we can identify the [pushforward/differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)) $$(R_g)_{\ast h}: T_hG\to T_{hg}G$$ with $R_g$.
3. Let $M$ denote spacetime, and let $f:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^4\to M$ be a local coordinate system. Let $p_0=f(x_0)$ be a spacetime point.
4. Ref. 1 is now considering a [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(fiber_bundle)) $\sigma: M\to G$. Let $g_0 := \sigma(p_0)\in G$.
5. Then
   $$X_{g_0}~:=~ \left. \partial_{\mu} (\sigma\circ f)(x)\right|_{x=x_0}~\in~T_{g_0}G,$$
   and hence OP's element belongs to the Lie algebra of the Lie group
   $$ (R_{g_0^{-1}})_{\ast g_0 } X_{g_0}~\in~T_eG~\equiv~\mathfrak{g}.$$

References:

1. G.B. Folland, *QFT: A Tourist Guide for Mathematicians,* 2008; p. 193.

Comment: thank you very much. that's a very detailed answer :))